# Form submission empty

Tags: forms, symfony, post

Submitting this:
[image]

But my entity and `$form->getData()` is empty (all the fields are null).

Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/persons", requirements={"_format" = "json"}, name="sales_persons_create")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function createAction()
{
$salesPerson = new SalesPerson();
$form = $this->createForm(new SalesPersonType(), $salesPerson);
$form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());
die(var_dump($salesPerson));
```

Comment: View the html of the form from your browser.  You will see that the input element names are more complicated than just "email".  S2 adds more info to support multiple forms and such.  Adjust your js to post the actual element names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm not sending the rendered form of Symfony2, the values are not matched as @Cerad stated.

However, Symfony still couldn't pick up the post values. The following example below allowed me to receive the post values (although I'm not sure of the workings):

```
$scope.saveLead = function() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('date', $scope.leadNew.date);
    formData.append('sales_person', $scope.leadNew.sales_person.id);
    formData.append('file', $scope.leadNew.file);
    leadsServ.create(formData).then(function(data) {
...
```

and a service example

```
     create: function(formData) {
            return $http.post(URL_SITE + '/categories', formData, {
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
                transformRequest: angular.identity
            }).then(function(result) {
                //console.info('leadsServ create', result.data);
                return result.data;
            });
        },
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you solved it?